# Как реализовать 2 основные категории в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Где определить и в дальнейшем прописывать категорию в ссылки если ссыль такого рода

localhost/category/controller/action

я так понимаю, что через urlManager постоянно приписывать активную категорию, а в каждом контроллере проверять активную
 есть ли другие и более правильные способы?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - два контроллера.
Или, один, но с настройкой роута.

```
'<type:[a-z]>-oborud/<action:\w+>' => 'oborud/<action>'
```

Comment: Спасибо!
2 контроллера думаю не пройдет, т.к. в каждой категории свои контроллеры.  
я перефразировал вопрос.

Comment: @Алим, тоже легко решается через правила в `CUrlManager`